# MS Access 2010 - Query only half populates drop down list sometimes?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a query of clients that populates a dropdown list in Access. This list has 41,000 items in it and is used to filter a certain client who you want to look at more information on. I would say 90% of the time the list works and all the clients show up. The other 10% of the time when you start typing a name it will only show half of the query in the dropdown. You then have to close access and reopen the database for it to work correctly. I also added a refresh button that refreshes the query but that did not seem to work. I cant figure out for the life of me why it only works 90% of the time. Any Suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

41,000 entries is a lot to put in a dropdown.

I couldn't find relevant answers on stackoverflow, see this link:

[Maximum records for combobox recordsource?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-access/maximum-records-for-combobox-recordsource/f7ae8cd5-dcae-40b1-b2e7-eb32ab381f3f)

Basically, make the user enter the first few characters of the client name before querying the combobox.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction....This gave me another idea similar to this one that will solve my problem. Cheers!